# “in a mood” or “in the mood”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, american-english

Could someone explain to me the difference between these two phrases (if there’s any at all)

According to Cambridge Online Dictionary

- **to be in the mood** means to feel like doing something
  *I am not really in the mood for shopping*.
- **to be in a mood** means to be not friendly to other people
  *Ignore him - he is in a mood.*

And is there a phrase: *It just goes on my mood* (with a context: it depends on my mood)? I watched an interview with Hailey Baldwin the other day and she was talking about her everyday outfits, saying that the pick of the outfit goes on her mood.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mood is a state of mind. If you are *in the mood to* do something, you are in the right state of mind to enjoy doing it. *In a mood* is just a short way of saying *in a bad mood*, that is, feeling angry or sulky.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of *in the mood* from the Merriam Webster

> Feeling a desire for something or to do something:
>
> I'm *in the mood* for sushi.

*In a mood* from the Cambridge Online dictionary (also in the question)

> To be in a mood means to be not friendly to other people:
>
> Ignore him - he is in a mood

*In a mood* however usually includes an understood negative, meaning something like *in a bad mood*.

Answer (score -1):

From Longman Dictionary of contemporary english be in a mood is to feel unhappy,impatient or angry and refuse to speak normally.
In the mood is feeling a desire for something or to do something